# Having problems with this Linq/Lambda statement :(

Tags: .net, linq, lambda

#### Update - I fixed the query below. I had the wrong query/error statement :(

I have the following statement:

```
var posts = BlogPostRepository.Find()
    .Where(x => x.Tags.Where(y => y.Name == tag))
    .ToList();
```

It's giving me a compile time error with the 2nd (inner) Where clause, saying :-

> > Error 1   Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

I'm trying to filter all BlogPosts by a specific tag name.

Comment: What is the "tag" identifier in your sample code?

Comment: @CesarGon Class that has an `int Id` and `string Name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part:

```
  x.Tags.Where(y => y.Name == tag)
```

will return an IEnumerable of whatever is in `Tags` that have `Name == tag`.  You are then comparing that to "true" which doesn't make much sense.

Perhaps you want this?

```
var posts = BlogPostRepository.Find()
    .Where(x => x.Tags.Any(y => y.Name == tag))
    .ToList()
```

or instead of Any, All?

Comment: He, thanks to your example I just realized that Any can be used like the IN SQL clause.

Comment: Sauce. Of. Awesome. (I also used Any and it returned all results, btw).